# Can anyone detemine the convergence of somewhat like p-series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Sorry for not familiar to Latex or anything like that.
I wonder about the convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{2-\sin(n)}}.
$$
At first I tried to use comparison test with proper p-series, but I failed to find proper p since $\sup \{\sin(n)\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is $1$, as far as I know.
Is there anyone can determine the convergence of the series?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what's the integral of 1/x^(2-sin(x))? How do you know that
improper intergral (1/x^(2-sin(x))) diverges?

Comment: Oh thanks. I now realized that Answer to the qustion is totally different from thinking the qustion. The prove is so hard.. I really feel thanksful to you.