# Can anyone detemine the convergence of series like p-series but with trigonometry function and prime?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

(A similar question I asked recently:
[Can anyone detemine the convergence of somewhat like p-series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695739/can-anyone-detemine-the-convergence-of-somewhat-like-p-series))
(Link for reference: [Convergence or divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2-\cos n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626391/convergence-or-divergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-cos-n))

Reference)We know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1}} = {\infty}$ & $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{nlogn} = {\infty}$ &

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{prime(n)} = {\infty}$ ($prime(n)$ ~ ${nlogn}$ for large n) &

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}} = \frac{\pi^2}{{6}}$

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{nlogn}$ and prime(n) is less denser than $\frac{1}{n}$ but dense enough to make the sum diverge. (prime(n) is the nth prime)
And, thanks to reference link, we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2-sin(n)}}$ also diverges, which implies 2-sin(n) gets close to 1 frequently enough to make the sum diverges.

Question. $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{nlogn}^{2-sin(n)}}$    or,
$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{nlogn}^{2-sin(nlogn)}}$    or    ,
$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{prime(n)}^{2-sin(n)}}$
diverges? or converges?